# Signals inside kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to write a device driver for a GSM modem that is connected through a serial interface. The basic idea is to send a command on the serial port and get a reply from the modem (if the command was successful the reply is OK and ERROR otherwise). The UART is generating an interrupt each time a character is sent from the modem and I've made a parser that puts each message from the modem in a list.
In order to configure the modem for sending or receiving SMS messages I have to send a sequence of commands to the modem. So from my modem_config() function I have to send a command wait for the response (OK or error) and if the reply was OK then send the next command and so on.
How can I wait in the modem_config() function for a signal from the parser that tells a reply from the modem is available? After I receive this signal modem_config() function will resume execution and interpret the reply from the modem.

Thanks.

Comment: By way of [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)?

Comment: *"I am trying to write a device driver for a GSM modem"* - IMO that is the wrong approach.  Write the handler for the GSM modem in userspace, and use an ordinary serial port driver.  The handler would configure the serial port to *raw mode* so that you can use the modem in either *command* mode or in *transparent* (aka *data*) mode.  Use ordinary `read()` and `write()` requests that will block to perform I/O in the handler.  If you insist on putting this modem handling in the kernel, then you should look at a driver tasklet.